# Is there a way to filter lines by charachter lenght in EmEditor

Tags: emeditor

I would like to search in a big text file and keep only lines that are between 9 and 20 charachters.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, click `Use Regular Expressions` and `Match Whole String` buttons on the **Filter** toolbar, and enter `.{9,20}` to the `Filter` drop-down list box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works pretty good. Is there a way to apply this filter on a file without opening it? It's because the file is too large.

Comment: While opening the file, click `Stop` in the `Large File Controller`, set the `Use Regular Expressions` option, and enter `^.{9,20}$`.